# TFS unshelve from root (main) to branch - unshelveing itself

Tags: tfs

Files are unshelved to root path rather then to the branch, here is the command I am running

```
tfpt unshelve "shelvset name" /migrate /source:$/Main /target:$/Branch1 .
/source : copied the server name from properties windows(right click the project folder-properties)
/target : copied the server name from properties
```

Comment: Can you post any messages you are getting from the TFPT command?

Comment: <pre>
creating the backup shelveset which will serve as a snapshot of your workspace's current state..
$/Main/somefilename: 
   open for edit in xxxxxx;
shelvset name Auto merge was successful.
</pre>

Answer (score 0):

My head stop sniping  here is the changes I did it works , put the source & target path with in double quotes and add the /migrate after unshelve.

```
tfpt unshelve /migrate shelvesetname;user "/source:$/Main" "/target:$/Branch1"
```